# Struct with forward_list with pointers to itself

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I'm implementing a very simpel model of a graph, in which I have a struct containing a forward list with pointers to it's neighbors. These neighbors are in turn structs of the same type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <forward_list>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Vertex Vertex;

struct Vertex {
    unsigned id;
    forward_list<Vertex*> _next;
};

typedef set<Vertex> Graph;
typedef vector<Vertex*> Index;
typedef pair<unsigned, unsigned> Edge;
typedef forward_list<Vertex*> Neighbors;


// Function:    process_line()
// Purpose:     process a specific line from the file.
// Params:      line to process
Edge process_line(string line){
    unsigned vertex_from;
    unsigned vertex_to;

    int idx = line.find(" ");

    vertex_from = (unsigned)stoul(line.substr(0, idx));
    vertex_to = (unsigned)stoul(line.substr(idx+1, line.length()));

    return make_pair(vertex_from, vertex_to);
}


// Function:    load_graph()
// Purpose:     load graph from file in relation
// Params:      path, and reference to graph and index
bool load_graph(string file_path, Graph &graph, Index &index){
    string line;
    ifstream file(file_path);
    bool foundEmptyLine = false;

    if(file.is_open()){
        while(getline(file, line)){
            if(line.empty()){
                foundEmptyLine = true;
            }

            if(!foundEmptyLine){
                // processing vertexes
                Vertex *vertex = new Vertex;

                vertex->id = stoul(line);
                graph.emplace(*vertex);
                index.emplace_back(vertex);
            }else{
                // Processing relations
                Edge edge = process_line(line);
                Vertex* neighbor = index.at(edge.second);

                // Lookup edge in index
                index.at(edge.first)->_next.push_front(neighbor);
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }else{
        cout << "Unable to open " << file_path;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void print_graph(Graph &graph){
    for(Graph::iterator it = graph.begin(); it != graph.end(); ++it){
        // Print item.
        cout << "Node: " << it->id << endl << "Neighbors:";

        for(Neighbors::iterator neigh = it->_next.begin(); neigh != it->_next.end(); ++neigh){
            // Print item.
            cout << (*neigh)->id;
        }
    }
}


// Entry point.
int main() {
    Graph graph;
    Index index;

    load_graph("graph_1.txt", graph, index);


    print_graph(graph);
}
```

It's all working out, until I try loop the vertexes in the graph, and subsequently loop all the neighbors of a vertex. (print_graph function) I'm getting this error:

> error: no viable conversion from 'const_iterator' (aka
>   '__forward_list_const_iterator *>') to 'Neighbors::iterator' (aka
>   '__forward_list_iterator *>')

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And where is there the loop?!

Comment: Print_graph method, should've mentioned it indeed.

Comment: it just tells you there what you need to do. You need to use Neighbors::const_iterator instead of iterator.

Comment: just as a comment (I guess you forgot to add this part of the code): You also need to have Vertex be less-comparable due to the emplace. As far as I can see from your question this is not thought as part of my answer, so I'll leave it here to avoid referring to two problems in my answer. I recommend adding this to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for this error is very subtle. `std::set`'s `iterator` type is practically identical to its `const_iterator` type. This makes sense; a set needs to guarantee at all times that every element is unique. It would not be able to give that guarantee if you could freely modify elements.

Consider the following line:

> ```
> for(Graph::iterator it = graph.begin(); it != graph.end(); ++it){
> ```

`it` is an `iterator` which acts like `const_iterator`. You cannot modify what the iterator points to.

You can verify this as follows:

```
it->id = 1; // will result in a compilation error
```

Then comes this line:

> ```
>     for(Neighbors::iterator neigh = it->_next.begin(); neigh != it->_next.end(); ++neigh){
> ```

`it->_next` is a `forward_list<Vertex*> const` due to the reasons explained above, and calling `begin()` on it therefore returns a `const_iterator`.

This is what finally causes the error: you cannot convert a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`.

The cure is easy: Just use `const_iterator`:

```
for(Neighbors::const_iterator neigh = it->_next.begin(); neigh != it->_next.end(); ++neigh){
```

Or even better, use `auto`:

```
for(auto neigh = it->_next.begin(); neigh != it->_next.end(); ++neigh){
```

Or even simpler, a range-based `for` loop:

```
for (auto const& neigh : it->_next) {
    // Print item.
    cout << neigh->id;
}
```

---

Note that once this particular error is fixed, you will find others. You are also missing a necessary `#include <string>`, which makes your code platform-dependent (i.e. it works with GCC, but not with Visual C++).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
Graph::iterator it = graph.begin()
```

will return an iterator of type `Graph::iterator` which is equal to `Graph::const_iterator`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set (note that this changed with C++11).

So when you then call

```
Neighbors::iterator neigh = it->_next.begin()
```

This will return a `std::forward_list::const_iterator` (because `*it` is `const`), which of course you cannot assign to a `std::forward_list::iterator`.

Anyway I would recommend using here `auto` for the types, and, because you don't need write-access anyway, you should use `cbegin()`, which returns a `const_iterator` in any case.